# Script que envie mensagem WhatsApp?

Tags: php, whatsapp

Existe a possibilidade de enviar mensagem **WhatsApp** através de um `Script PHP`? *(Como se fosse um SMS ou e-mail)*
Encontrei uma classe, mas ela é antiga e já não funciona mais *(os servidores mudaram, com a venda do WhatsApp e necessita de uma senha que não consegui encontrar [**vinculada à conta de usuário do whatsapp**])*.

Comment: Existe uma API chamada **[WhatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI)** que permite fazer o que você quer. No entanto, parece que a API está enfrentando problemas jurídicos já que o WhatsApp não possui uma API pública como o Twitter, Hangouts e outros serviços e essa API "expõe" o WhatsApp. Bom, fica de olho e veja se ela te ajuda. Mas não há garantia nenhuma. Acredito que [esse post](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/07/send-whatsapp-messages-via-php-script-using-whatsapi/) também possa te ajudar.

Comment: Foi justamente esse API que eu encontrei, no entanto ela necessita da senha do WhatsApp (vinculada ao usuário), que é criptografada e tudo mais, realizei uns testes aqui (sem senha mesmo) mas os servidores foram alterados... Acredito que não seja mais possível fazer isso, por isso perguntei aqui (pra não ficar procurando à toa)...

Comment: E nesse caso, ao enviar a mensagem, o seu usuário acabaria sendo o remetente da mensagem. Certo?

Comment: Então, eu utilizei meu usuário (conforme a API pede), ou seja, inclui meu número de celular (com o código do país e do estado [DDD]) e o código IMEI (id do usuário, através da chamada *#06#). A senha, eu testei com ela em branco "", alguns números "1234567890", e testei também o método login() (que, conforme a API, não necessita de senha mas apaga todos os dados do usuário, pelo que entendi)... Mas, o problema é que ocorre um erro antes do Login (logo na conexão), onde a função fsockopen() retorna false ao chamar o servidor "c.whatsapp.net" pela porta 443 (conforme o padrão da própria API).

Comment: Que isso gente a whatsApi funciona bem demais baixei hoje compilei e gerei a senha tranqüilamente.

Comment: Se a API não estiver funcionando recomendo que leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130096/3635

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Formulando uma resposta.

Como bem informado pelo @Ricardo Giaviti, existe uma API chamada [WhatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI), que permite que você faça o que quer fazer. Porém esta só funciona com a sua senha do Whatsapp. O problema é pegar ela. Você precisa utilizar o `mitmproxy` pra *"sniffar"(por assim dizer)* seu password.
Essa é a parte mais difícil, depois fica *"simples"*.

Segue forma de fazer:

1. [Este post](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/05/how-to-sniff-the-whatsapp-password-from-your-android-phone-or-iphone/) vai te ajudar a pegar o password da sua conta do **Whatsapp**.
2. [Este post](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/07/send-whatsapp-messages-via-php-script-using-whatsapi/) vai te ajudar a utilizar o [WhatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI).

Comment: Sobre a senha, encontrei um outro site (http://limontec.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/tutorial-enviar-mensagens-whatsapp-via.html) que também menciona o site do Sr. Phillips, e frisa que o método para obter a senha não funciona mais: (... mas logo a WhatsApp Inc descobriu a vulnerabilidade e a corrigiu).

E os comentários do site do Phillips (os mais recentes, é claro), dão indícios de que esse envio não é mais possível :/

Comment: Li em algum lugar (vou ficar devendo a fonte) que o WhatsApp considera ilegal o acesso ao serviço sem ser pelo aplicativo deles. Portanto use qualquer uma dessas APIs paralelas (oficial não existe) por sua conta e risco.

Comment: Resume de algumas regras do Whatsapp (https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/)
3. WhatsApp Access:
 * "you will not attempt to reverse engineer, alter or modify any part of the Service"
 * "you are not permitted to resell or charge others for use of or access to the Service"
 * "You agree not to use or launch any automated system...that sends more request messages to the WhatsApp servers in a given period of time than a human can reasonably produce in the same period by using a WhatsApp application"
 * "You agree not to spam, or solicit for commercial purposes, any users of the Service"

Comment: O repositorio foi eliminado, o autor foi ameaçado com ação judicial pela WhatsApp

Comment: Essa API serve para desenvolvimento em Delphi?