# Enviar mensagem via whatsapp programaticamente

Tags: android, whatsapp

Tentei alguns códigos mas não consegui nada ainda. Estou levantando a possibilidade de enviar de um-a-um percorrendo um loop. Alguém sabe como?
Segue tutorial que tentei

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946461/send-message-by-viber-or-whatsapp-programmatically

Detalhe: Quero apenas enviar, e não começar um chat!
Neste caso, envio a mensagem e fecho o chat.

Comment: Que erros você obteve ao tentar esses tutoriais?

Comment: É mais produtivo você publicar aqui o código que está trabalhando.

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Simplesmente não vai. Não funciona. Eu executo e nada acontece. Não chega a mensagem no destino, e não dar erro algum! O Código, é o mesmo do tutorial...

Comment: Isto é pra php, mas pode ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10110/script-que-envie-mensagem-whatsapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta isso

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolvedInfoList) {
    if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith(getString(R.string.whatsapp_package_name))) {
        intent.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);        
        break;
    }
}
intent.setPackage(getString(R.string.whatsapp_package_name));//com.whatsapp
String text = "Texto a ser compartilhado";
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
startActivity(intent);
```

É bom você verificar se o usuário tem o WhatsApp instalado

Comment: Consegui resolver com insert no banco. Depois eu faço uma chamada no processo com.whatsapp e ele envia as mensagens.