# Enviar mensagem para WhatsApp via site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, whatsapp

Gostaria de saber se existe como enviar mensagem para WhatsApp através de site. Exemplo: O cliente está lá no site e existe um campo para digitar uma mensagem e clicar em "enviar" e eu receber a mensagem no meu WhatsApp.

Comment: Não existe, pois infringe os [termos de uso da aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221574/5878).

Comment: Aproveita e leia [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221574/28595)

Comment: Acredito que você pode encontrar a resposta que procura [nesse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10122/51759).

Comment: Oi, existe já uma API do whatsapp: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567 essa é a forma legal que existe para fazer isso, segue o link explicando como ela funciona:
https://faq.whatsapp.com/pt_br/android/26000030/?category=5245251

Comment: Se é permitido utilizar determinado recurso ou não desconheço, embora informação nunca é demais. Agradeço por todas as informações e respostas. Particularmente achei mimimi o fechamento desta pergunta, pois até aonde conheço é sim uma pergunta que busca informações sobre programação.

Comment: Achei interessante esse método. Eu fiz de uma maneira um pouco diferente, mas já adiciona direto o número aos contatos. Pra quem quiser ver mais detalhes, segue o link: https://lucianobragaweb.github.io/post/whatsapp-no-site/

Comment: Até agora não entendi o motivo do fechamento desta pergunta, cujo conteúdo é de legítimo interesse de fullstack developers. (Votando para reabrir).

Comment: A API de envio está sendo criada, porém é para empresas. Link da API: https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api 
Link do formulário de cadastro para uso da API (querer aprovação do Facebook): https://www.facebook.com/business/m/whatsapp/business-api

Comment: Tbm achei muito mimimi a pergunta ter sido fechada, pois é de grande interesse para programadores, inclusive estou com essa demanda atualmente!

Comment: Também quer entender o motivo do fechamento da pergunta, @AllanAndrade. Até hoje ela poderia estar sendo aprimorada, já que muita coisa nova foi feita nesse tempo.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Pergunta corriqueira más interessante do ponto de vista que há possibilidade sim de escrever uma mensagem em um website e usando os mecanismos oficiais do `WhatsApp` para tal enviá-la.

Em um comentário realizado por [@Gabriel Moodlight](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/51759/gabriel-moodlight) referencia o seguinte post: [Script que envie mensagem WhatsApp?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10122/51759)
 contudo é uma postagem antiga e como referenciado nos primeiros comentários o seguinte post: [Como integrar a aplicação com Whatsapp? [fechada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221574/28595)
 tem uma resposta mais recente e que explica que a biblioteca [WhatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI) foi descontinuada.

> Como fazer então?

É possível utilizar o **endpoint ["send"](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251)** da interface web do `WhatsApp` ou mesmo o link **send** no caso de um acesso mobile.

Os parâmetros válidos são **phone** e **text** podendo utilizar ambos ou apenas um.

Aqui presume-se 2 paradigmas:

- **1**: primeiro que o usuário utilize em seu navegador o `WhatsApp Web`
- **2**: que o usuário tenha o aplicativo `WhatsApp` em seu dispositivo móvel

Esta abordagem é exatamente igual a os **endpoints** utilizados por várias redes e sites de grande volume na web onde o serviço disponibiliza uma `URL` para acessos via método `GET` ou `POST` para compartilhamento de conteúdo externo para a plataforma.

Para usar este **endpoint** no `WhatsApp Web` (ou mobile) pode-se enviar apenas o texto e isso fará com que o usuário selecione de sua lista de contatos o número para o qual enviará ou, definir um número no formato internacional (apenas números).

Tanto a mensagem ou o número devem ser encodados com `URL-encode`.

Um exemplo que pode ser usado no front-end:

```
// um número no formato internacional (ativo no WhatsApp)
let number = '55519xxxxxxxx'
// o texto ou algo vindo de um <textarea> ou <input> por exemplo
let msg = 'Um texto qualquer'

// montar o link (apenas texto) (web)
let target = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=${encodeURIComponent(msg)}`

// montar o link (número e texto) (web)
let target = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${encodeURIComponent(number)}&text=${encodeURIComponent(msg)}`

// montar o link (texto) (app)
let target `whatsapp://send?text=${encodeURIComponent(msg)}`

// montar o link (número e texto) (app)
let target `whatsapp://send?text=${encodeURIComponent(msg)}`
```

Estes exemplos podem ser usados por uma apicação **"web"** (website) tanto pelo acesso em um navegador desktop ou mobile.

Se o acesso for via dispositivo móvel o navegador ira lançar o aplicativo por causa do protocolo `whatsapp://` já pelo acesso desktop irá para o site.

> Isto não enviará uma mensagem diretamente. Isto irá abrir a interface para interação do usuário.

**Exemplo Web**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No website a interface mostrará ao usuário o número e o texto requerendo assim a confirmação da ação...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo após irá abrir o editor. Basta o usuário clicar em enviar e pronto.

Caso o usuário não esteja autenticado no site [web.whatsapp.com](https://web.whatsapp.com) ele não poderá prosseguir (enviar) e lhe será informado que deves se autenticar na aplicação. Já no dispositivo caso o usuário não tenha o aplicativo o navegador irá ser apresentado uma lista de aplicativos com o qual o sistema tentará abrir o protocolo (normalmente más não é padrão).

---

Para definir a abordagem (URL ou protocolo) poderia simplesmente verificar se o acesso é móvel ou não:

```
// fonte: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
let isMobile = (function(a) {
    if ( /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)) ) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);

// checar
if ( isMobile ) {
    // usar o protocolo
} else {
    // usar o URL
}
```

Se irá utilizar um link ou abrir um modal fica a critério do programador.

**usando URL (link)**:

```
let a = document.createElement('a')
a.target = '_blank'
a.href = target // o link URL do api.whatsapp.com
a.click() // simular o evento de "click"
```

**usando `window.open()`**

```
let h = 650,
    w = 550,
    l = Math.floor(((screen.availWidth || 1024) - w) / 2),
    t = Math.floor(((screen.availHeight || 700) - h) / 2)
// definir
let options = `height=600,width=550,top=${t},left=${l},location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0`
// abrir
let popup = window.open(target, 'self', options)
// forçar o focus()
if ( popup ) {
    popup.focus()
}
```

Navegadores mobile podem ter restrições mais rígidas ao lançar `window.open()` por isso usar um link talvez seja mais útil.

> Não é possível anexar arquivos com este método nem adicionar parâmetros extras!

**Execute o código abaixo para testar**:

```js
let phone = document.getElementById('phone')
let message = document.getElementById('message')

// buttons
let linkHandler = document.getElementById('by-link')
let popUpHandler = document.getElementById('by-popup')

// font: 
let isMobile = (function(a) {
    if ( /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)) ) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera)

const makeLink = function(mode) {

    let mount = function() {
        if ( isMobile ) {
            let target = `whatsapp://send?`
            if ( !!phone && phone.value !== '' ) {
                target += `phone=${encodeURIComponent(phone.value)}&`
            }
            if ( !!message && message.value !== '' ) {
                target += `text=${encodeURIComponent(message.value)}`
            }
            return target
        } else {
            let target = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?`
            if ( !!phone && phone.value !== '' ) {
                target += `phone=${encodeURIComponent(phone.value)}&`
            }
            if ( !!message && message.value !== '' ) {
                target += `text=${encodeURIComponent(message.value)}`
            }
            return target
        }
    
    }

    let openLink = function() {
        $('#console-container').append(`<span class="col px-0"><b>Link</b>: ${mount()}</span><br><br>`)
    }

    let openPopUp = function() {
        let h = 650,
            w = 550,
            l = Math.floor(((screen.availWidth || 1024) - w) / 2),
            t = Math.floor(((screen.availHeight || 700) - h) / 2)
        // open popup
        let options = `height=600,width=550,top=${t},left=${l},location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0`
        $('#console-container').append(`<span class="col px-0"><b>PopUp URL</b>: ${mount()}</span><br><span class="col px-0"><b>PopUp options</b>: ${options}</span><br><br>`)
    }
    
    switch (mode) {
        case 'link':
            openLink()
        break
        case 'popup':
            openPopUp()
        break
    }
} 




// events handler(s)
linkHandler.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    makeLink('link')
}, false)
popUpHandler.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    makeLink('popup')
}, false)
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- CONTAINER -->
<section class="container-fluid px-0 pt-5">

    <div class="col col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-4 mx-auto px-0 mb-5">
        <form accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <label>Phone (international)</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 fa fa-whatsapp"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input id="phone" type="phone" class="form-control rounded-0">
                </div>
            
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <label>Message</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input id="message" type="text" class="form-control rounded-0">
                </div>
            
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <label>Enviar</label>
                <div class="col px-0">
                    <button id="by-link" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Link</button>
                    <button id="by-popup" type="button" class="btn btn-info">PopUp</button>
                 </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
    
    <div id="console-container" class="col col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-4 mx-auto px-0 mb-5">
    
    
    </div>

</section>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

O trecho acima é executado em uma `sandbox` por isso adicionei os eventos ao simples **"output"**... para testar realment através de `window.open()` ou simulando o evento `click()`: [veja esta demo](https://subversivo58.github.io/lab/whatsapp-send.html)

Comment: A API de envio está sendo criada, porém é para empresas. Link da API: https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api 
Link do formulário de cadastro para uso da API (querer aprovação do Facebook): https://www.facebook.com/business/m/whatsapp/business-api

Comment: cara achei excelente, muito esclarecedor, eu estou tentando descobrir se tem como depois que a pessoa clicar no link, ao abrir no celular que seja feito o envio de forma automática sem precisar clicar em enviar, será possível?

Comment: @WPfan resposta curta: **não**. A interação do usuário é necessária para que o mesmo possa ver o texto e o destinatário ... do contrário seria uma brecha de segurança aberta/escancarada para **"spamers"**.

Comment: Eu vi um sistema desktop fazendo isso cara, um sistema de captura de leads fazendo essa parada ai, por isso que to no encalço pra descobrir como foi feito!!! @LauroMoraes por isso acho que é possível de alguma forma criar esse bot!