# Link "Compartilhar no WhatsApp"

Tags: php, wordpress

Com base neste código

```
        <li><a class="whatsapp" title="<?php esc_html_e( 'Compartilhar no WhatsApp', 'grandmagazine' ); ?>" target="_blank" href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php the_permalink() ?>&url=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
```

Onde estou errando que não funciona naminha página o compartilhamento?

Aparece assim

whatsapp://send?text=http://tucnews.com.br/bica-como-funciona-a-mais-popular-fonte-de-agua-de-tucurui-2/&url=http://tucnews.com.br/bica-como-funciona-a-mais-popular-fonte-de-agua-de-tucurui-2/

No navegador, mas a página fica em branco.

Este é um código que funciona para o Facebook

```
    <li><a class="facebook" title="<?php esc_html_e( 'Compartilhar no Facebook', 'grandmagazine' ); ?>" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
```

Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 7):

Normalmente a comunidade tende a fechar este tipo de pergunta (relacionada ao WhatsApp), erroneamente na minha opinião.

As perguntas relacionadas normalmente não compreendem a API relacionada a função **"share"** do WhatsAPP e suas peculiaridades, que não são em nada diferente de outros grandes serviços como Facebook, Twitter, etc... que disponibilizao um **"endpoint"** para o usuário compartilhar na rede conteúdo e informação externa.

Duas perspectivas devem ser observadas aqui:

- se o usuário esta acessando a partir de um dispositivo móvel
- se o usuário esta acessando a partir de um desktop

O **"endpoint"** do WhatsApp aceita apenas dois parametros: **phone** e **text** e ambos devem ter o conteúdo encodado, no seu caso usando PHP seria algo como

```
<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>
```

Deve-se notar que o campo **phone** deve estar no formato internacional (código do pais + codigo de área + número de telefone) apenas em números, exemplo:

```
// Brasil DDD (RS) número (omitido por X)
5551XXXXXXXXX
```

Dependendo da perspectiva (mobile ou desktop) o **endpoind** muda.

Para uma navegação **mobile** deve-se usar o protocolo `whatsapp://send?` que irá abrir o aplicativo caso este esteja instalado no aparelho do usuário, do contrario irá abrir a interface do sistema para o usuário escolher uma aplicação para abrir este tipo de protocolo.

Já na navegação **desktop** usa-se o link `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?` que irá para o dominio da aplicação web do WhatsApp (PWA), caso o usuário não tenha usado esta aplicação anteriormente (não fez login) ele será informado do mesmo.

Esta função não envia automaticamente, ela abre uma janela para confirmação do usuário. Caso ele confirme então abre o diálogo onde o usuário deve então clicar no botão de envio.

Se o parãmetro **phone** for suprimido a aplicação WhatsApp (desktop ou mobile) irá abrir um modal para o usuário escolher para quem quer enviar o conteudo, lista de contatos ou mesmo seus grupos.

Eu não acho que seja duplicata mas com certeza sua pergunta pode ser relacionada a outra aqui na comunidade ao qual já inclusive respondi: [Enviar mensagem para WhatsApp via site [fechada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266518/enviar-mensagem-para-whatsapp-via-site/266551#266551)

Vale a pena dar uma olhada nesta uma vez que, a "mágica" para traçar uma abordagem mais correta acontece no `frontend` (javascript).

Este inclusive é meu demo já publicado na pergunta supracitada como relacionada: [DEMO](https://subversivo58.github.io/lab/whatsapp-send.html)

---

Fonte: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251

Comment: Oxi, o **hater** de plantão poderia enriquecer a questão apresentando uma resposta "melhor" ou comentando para "podermos" saber no que melhorar a resposta prestada...só passar pra dar **downvote** porque não entendeu a questão (ou a resposta) deve ser muita amargura no coração. Só acho.

Comment: Sempre tem uns trouxas... ótima resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, o seu erro, e porque esse link só vai funcionar em mobile.. ou seja só vai abrir se você estiver acessando esse link com um celular, com WhatsApp instalado para poder funcionar.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Caso não tenha WhastApp instalado no celular, vai ficar pagina em branco também.

Comment: Se tiver o WhatsApp Web ativado no desktop irá funcionar também.

Comment: Pelo contrário. Funciona no desktop, mas quando compartilho pelo celular redireciona para o navegador do celular pedindo para instalar whatsapp.