# Criar um follow icone em html

Tags: html

Olá! Estou desenvolvendo um site ecommerce em uma plataforma com programação html. E o cliente solicitou para colocar um atalho para acessar o whataspp. Como eu faço a programação do “follow” em html?

Comment: Oi, Paula! Você poderia deixar sua pergunta um pouco mais clara? É que, até onde sei, o `Whatsapp` não é um aplicativo de seguir. Então, entendi que você quer usar um botão para compartilhar o post ou link via `Whatsapp`. Poderia deixar sua pergunta mais clara? Desde já, obrigada! 

Comment: Alguns links de referencias: [001](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266518/enviar-mensagem-para-whatsapp-via-site), [002](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/320074/link-compartilhar-no-whatsapp), [003](https://subversivo58.github.io/lab/whatsapp-send.html)

Comment: Na vdd eu quero colocar uma imagem do icone do whatsapp e depois colocar um link para disponibilizar o whatsapp das vendedoras. Algo como feito para o site https://www.minhacasasolar.com.br/

Comment: @PaulaLutzoff, caso alguma resposta tenha resolvido o seu problema você pode marcar como aceita clicando no V verdinho do lado dos pontos da escolhida. Ou, caso queira, pode deixar em aberto mais um tempo se deseja mais alternativas, mas é bom que depois de resolvida você marque alguma para fechar o assunto. Saiba mais em ["Como e por que aceitar uma resposta"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Answer (score 0):

Com base no exemplo do site que você passou como referência você poderia fazer algo assim [execute o snippet em tela cheia para visualizar o exemplo]:

```css
.fixed-tabs-Whats {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -170px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.aba-whatsphone {
  background: #1EBEA5;
  height: 60px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
  transition: 0.7s ease;
}

.aba-whatsphone:hover {
  width: 280px;
  transition: 0.7s ease;
}

.aba-whatsphone-icone {
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/WhatsApp.svg/1024px-WhatsApp.svg.png') no-repeat; 
  width: 280px;
  background-size: 50px;
  background-position-y: 4px;
  background-position-x: 14px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.aba-whatsphone-icone a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.aba-whatsphone-icone a strong {
  display: block;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-tabs-Whats">
  <div class="aba-whatsphone">
    <div class="aba-whatsphone-icone">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5500000000000&text=D%C3%BAvida%20Site">Clique aqui <br><strong>e entre em contato!</strong></a>       
    </div>
  </div>          
</div>
```

Para o link de contato do WhatsApp você pode utilizar a API do mesmo e trocar o número fictício do exemplo para o desejado.

Além disso você pode também tirar a mensagem que aparece ao passar o cursor do mouse sobre o ícone do WhatsApp.

Comment: O que eu preciso acrescentar para que o link possa acompanhar o scroll da pagina?

Comment: Ele já foi projetado para acompanhar o scroll da página.

Comment: Mais nao está acompanhando .. quando rolo a pagina, ele some

Comment: Olha essa [página](https://codepen.io/jpedroschmitz/pen/QVvamY) e redimensiona para testar em páginas menores. Ao diminuir verá que gerou scroll na página e o ícone o acompanha.