# Dificuldades em fazer funcionar o código-fonte do botão do Whatsapp no HTML

Tags: html, css, whatsapp

Estou criando um site de vendas e **adicionei um o botão de contato de Whatsapp que fica no rodapé da página (está flutuante se não me engano)**, mesmo eu espelhando o Whatsapp para o navegador web ele **aparece a mensagem de erro dizendo que a página não existe**.

Alguém pode me ajudar a contornar isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="https://wa.me/55(77912345678)?text=Entrar%20em%20contato" style="position:fixed;width:60px;height:60px;bottom:40px;right:40px;background-color:#25d366;color:#FFF;border-radius:50px;text-align:center;font-size:30px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
  z-index:1000;" target="_blank">
<i style="margin-top:16px" class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Segundo a documetação para usar o endpoint: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251. O número deve estar ativo no whatsapp, em formato internacional (apenas números) e ambos, número e mensagem devem ser encodados com URI-encode. Uma resposta que talves ajude no entendimento: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266518/enviar-mensagem-para-whatsapp-via-site/266551#266551

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?lang=pt_pt), seu link está incorreto. Em vez de:

https://wa.me/55(77912345678)?text=Entrar%20em%20contato

Seria:

https://wa.me/5577912345678?text=Entrar%20em%20contato

> Os números em sequência (`cód. país + cód. área (DDD) + telefone`) sem parênteses ou outro caractere.

Answer (score 1):

Substitua o endereço do link por este:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5577912345678&text=Entrar%20em%20contato

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5577912345678&text=Entrar%20em%20contato" style="position:fixed;width:60px;height:60px;bottom:40px;right:40px;background-color:#25d366;color:#FFF;border-radius:50px;text-align:center;font-size:30px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
  z-index:1000;" target="_blank">
<i style="margin-top:16px" class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitui o link
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=**77912345678**&text=Entrar%20em%20contato

Por esse aqui:
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5577912345678&text=Entrar%20em%20contato

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5577912345678&text=Entrar%20em%20contato" style="position:fixed;width:60px;height:60px;bottom:40px;right:40px;background-color:#25d366;color:#FFF;border-radius:50px;text-align:center;font-size:30px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
  z-index:1000;" target="_blank">
<i style="margin-top:16px" class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
</a>
```